# Is it possible to play any sound file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to make scary sound effects for my game, and I was wondering if I could make scary ambience. Is there any way I can play any sound file?

Answer (score 7):

Use `/playsound [player] [sound]`. There is a full documentation at the Minecraft Wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#playsound). I have used the command in the past, and you can also make a custom resource pack with a sound you wish to play.